# Upload file through API

Tags: laravel, api

I am updating data using API request like below.

```
$response = Http::withToken(Session::get('SesTok'))->post('https://sometext/profile-update', [
                "first_name" => $request->first_name,
                "last_name" => $request->last_name,
                "email" => $request->profile_email,       
            ]);
```

Now I need to upload **File**  using API Request. I can fetch file details using `$request->file('logo')`.

How can I Upload file through API ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Http::attach` method

```
    $response = Http::attach(
    'attachment', file_get_contents('photo.jpg'), 'photo.jpg'
    )->post('http://example.com/attachments');
```

Comment: Thanks @Shahrukh. Should I use like this ? `$response = Http::attach(
    'attachment', file_get_contents($request->file('logo')), 'photo.jpg'
)->post('http://example.com/attachments');`

Comment: use `file_get_contents($request->file('logo')->getRealPath());`